# GitHub API not returning line number

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to use the v3 GitHub API to create a comment on the line. Rhe documentation says the following:

> Note: To comment on a specific line in a file, you need to first determine the position of that line in the diff. The GitHub REST API v3 offers the application/vnd.github.v3.diff media type. To see a pull request diff, add this media type to the Accept header of a call to the single pull request endpoint.

[Link](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment) to the documentation. But when I try to do a request it replies:

```
[
        {
            "sha": "7ed12345678911cd0d8c6bf34fa547aaa6eab5b6",
            "filename": "README.md",
            "status": "modified",
            "additions": 1,
            "deletions": 1,
            "changes": 2,
            "blob_url": "https://github.com/johnsnow/demo/blob/37422b7241b0dadcdac1af53f8e33baba7b489bd/README.md",
            "raw_url": "https://github.com/johnsnow/demo/raw/37422b7241b0dadcdac1af53f8e33baba7b489bd/README.md",
            "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/johnsnow/demo/contents/README.md?ref=37422b7241b0dadcdac1af53f8e33baba7b489bd",
            "patch": "@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@\n # Application model for Java 8\n \n-We provide a basic model for JDK 1.8 / Spark based web applications.\n+AWe provide a basic model for JDK 1.8 / Spark based web applications."
        }
 ]
```

The API isn't showing me the diff.

Example of the request:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.github.com/repos/johnsnow/demo/pulls/20/files?access_token=some_token' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the last sentence in the documentation you referenced:

> To see a pull request diff, add this media type to the Accept header of a call to the [single pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request) endpoint.

However you are requesting the ["List pull requests files" endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files). Remove `/files` from the end of your request URL:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.github.com/repos/johnsnow/demo/pulls/20?access_token=some_token' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff'
```